# What does Pr(dx, dy) mean?

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, measure-theory, machine-learning

The book [The Elements of Statistical Learning by Hastie and others](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf) (page 18) defines the expected value of prediction error as
\begin{align}
 \operatorname{EPE}(f) &= \operatorname E(Y - f(X))^2\\
 & = \int [y - f(x)]^2 \Pr(dx, dy)
\end{align}

Why is it like above?
Why not as below to be consistent with any expected value definition?
$$ \operatorname{EPE}(f) = E(Y - f(x))^2 = \iint  [y - f(x)]^2  \Pr(x,y) d(x) d(y)$$
What does $\Pr(dx, dy)$ even mean?

Comment: I fixed the formula you miscopied.

Comment: What does $d(x,y)$ mean? This is not standard notation either. And aren't you missing an integral sign in your proposed formula?

Comment: @littleO Yes, I fixed the missing integral now. Thanks! I guess you are right about d(x, y) too. I changed it to d(x) d(y) now.

Comment: Not sure if the notation is well-defined. It is more clear if we write $$\Bbb{E}[ (Y - f(X))^2 ] = \int (y - f(x))^2 \, \Bbb{P}(X \in dx, Y \in dy). $$ Here, $\Bbb{P}(X \in dx, Y \in dy)$ is a shorthand notation for the probability measure which is specified by the cdf $(x, y) \mapsto \Bbb{P}(X \leq x, Y \leq y)$. This is in some sense a generalization of the 'change of variables' formula, since the LHS is an integral $$\Bbb{E}[ (Y - f(X))^2 ] =  \int_{\Omega} (Y(\omega) - f(X(\omega)))^2 \, \Bbb{P}(d\omega) $$ and we are making substitution $(x, y) = (X(\omega), Y(\omega))$.

Comment: Ah, I read the relevant page just now and it is explicitly stated that $\mathrm{Pr}(X, Y)$ denotes the joint distribution of $(X, Y)$. Then the notation makes sense, exactly the same way I described above.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee What does P(dω) mean?

Comment: If you have never been exposed to (abstract) measure theory, then it would take a couple of lectures to explain the mathematical background behind it. But the basics is not hard to explain. Simply imagine that the whole sample space $\Omega$ consists of a plethora of *'infinitesimal pieces'*, each of which denoted by the generic notation $d\omega$ and having probability $\Bbb{P}(d\omega)$. Then the integral can be understood as the Riemann sum $\sum (Y(\omega) - f(X(\omega)))^2 \, \Bbb{P}(d\omega)$, where $\omega$ is any sample in each infinitesimally small event $d\omega$.

Comment: So measure theory is what is missing in my knowledge here! Thanks a lot. That is a big help to know.  Also thanks for the nice explanation! :)

Comment: What you take "any expected value definition" is generally regarded by mathematicians as a theorem rather than as a definition. The book you mention gives an integral that is an instance of what is generally treated as the definition. (But what exactly is a _definition_ changes as understanding evolves, and varies with the context.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are dealing with a probability density function. Since this is a bivariate density function our function outputs density per unit area (hence why an output $f(x,y)$ is not a valid probability measure on its own, and there is no restriction that $f(x,y) \leq 1$).

So we can argue for *very small* $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$, $\Pr(\Delta x, \Delta y) \approx f(x,y) \, \Delta x \, \Delta y$ and in the limit as $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ go to 0 we have $\Pr(dx, dy) = f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$.

Answer (score 2):

By the definition of a density function the probability of x being in an infinitesimal range [x, x + dx] is

Pr(dx)=f(x)dx

We can extend this to the two variable situation in which case;

Pr(dx, dy) = f(x,y)dx dy

Answer (score 1):

They use this notation to avoid having to distinguish cases where the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are continuous, discrete, or a mix of these. In general, when you see a notation like $\int_A g(x) P(dx)$ or $\int_A g(x) dP$, you can expand it to $\int_A g(x) p(x) dx$ if $X$ is continuous, and to $\sum_{x \in A} g(x) p(x)$ if $X$ is discrete, where $p(x)$ is the probability density/mass function respectively derived[1] from $P(\cdot)$.

If you want to understand more about this notation, you have to read an introductory chapter in measure theory. Since $P(\cdot)$ is a measure, it must be evaluated on sets. The notation $P(dx)$ refers to the measure $P(\cdot)$ evaluated at a small ball around $x$. Recall the interpretation of an integral as a sum. The notation $\int_A g(x) P(dx)$ means: cover the set $A$ with balls $dx$ centered around several points $x$ and sum $g(x)P(dx)$.

[1] $p$ is called the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $P$ with respect to the dominating measure in each case, i.e. the Lebesgue measure in the continuous case, and the counting measure in the discrete case. Confusingly, some authors use the same symbol to denote both the measure and its derivative.